# Keycloak JWT generation

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, keycloak

I have keycloak running in localhost. I am testing it to generate a token. I have used an example I found. The token is the following:

```
 "access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJGSjg2R2NGM2pUYk5MT2NvNE52WmtVQ0lVbWZZQ3FvcXRPUWVNZmJoTmxFIn0.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.n1K0KIGYJYPZkjSq1eSg5gWnCAj44mgl4M-GJOlzgCj8y5TGw5OhT7sr84o9Ja9K6WMW3t0ti6feZIgc8mps3RK0HuuXeCNcrN6H2dPEtBphTvfXEUR2iMg83iCmxjhXgXso7oX2vyreJqB6WCCFEPbAQH2e5kHZqv6cfmXRlYU"
```

For the realm I have created I have an RSA public key and a certificate. 
I copy the token in https://jwt.io/ in order to check if it is valid, I also copy this public key *VERIFY SIGNATURE* section but the token is invalid somehow. Is my token valid or not? How can I produce a valid token?

Comment: Can you please provide more inof on how you generated jwt? Or perhaps you can answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877229/keycloak-how-to-generate-jwt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jwt.io expects a PEM format, so paste your public key from keycloak between `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` and it will work.
You can use this one and replace it with your key :

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoizQyv6WlRw3pPJNvrs9wYoc0hCU2hJ8bdwElevC2Vk/IrnN06mv1AotNpsmkrhNMBHU0iyBDl6ZCdyPDuOrKpuId1eURjfLP7s2V3+KA+x/H6TQFaFGKwEUiTx8oMZh+StBMz8tifHQlsm2VAIl920C1PgDTx7PcpDMz/g0/bnDdq8IDCgAi5rMTblzi+hTh4BO3wcA5EE7Iz1NymlTR0UXgMwS/gNuH+UM1fg8pxcZPM0YtHBBHIXaTqsI6nxfOi2e8JwvS2slKB/I3w66Kl+mNWEdXke5mh724yeQ3oRU/lQAlU8u+zRYFZRuLi06mMv42F+GLCmP9XZCyfFeQQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

[image]